# how to access a header template in c#

Tags: c#, css

I have a template:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="litFolder" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="litFolder_ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul class="test" id="currentLink">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="leftNav">
            <li>
               <asp:HyperLink ID="innerHyperLink" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
            </li>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and I'm trying to set the  to display block when a link is selected. I can set the link to display block, but how do I set the ul to display block ( only using C# )

```
    protected void litFolder_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        // if the child from the first repeater has children, it will grab them here
        Item innerItem = (Item)e.Item.DataItem;

        if (innerItem != null)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                // this creates a link to the page in sitecore once clicked
                HyperLink topNavigation = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("innerHyperLink");
                topNavigation.NavigateUrl = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(innerItem);
                topNavigation.Text = innerItem["Title"];

                if (topNavigation != null) {
                   //this is where I think I need to define the ul to display block
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I need to make sure that the current link sets the ul that it is in and not all the ul's with the class test.

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent the `Ul` from being broken, place the `<div class="leftNav">` inside the `<li>` as shown below:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="litFolder" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="litFolder_ItemDataBound">
<HeaderTemplate>
    <ul class="test" id="currentLink">
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
        <li>
         <div class="leftNav">
           <asp:HyperLink ID="innerHyperLink" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
         </div>
        </li>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
    </ul>
</FooterTemplate>
```

To set the display block style, you can find the control based on the ID, then set the style to it.

Thanks